# Where is my .bash_profile located? (Mac OS 10.10.5)

Tags: terminal, bash, python, path

Disclamer: I am a newbie to UNIX programming.

I downloaded Anaconda but then realized that I did not need it. I deleted and uninstalled it as fully as I could find out how. It seems that everything to do with Anaconda is gone except that the $PATH variable retains paths to folders which no longer exist.

In the terminal when I type

```
echo $PATH
```

It returns

`/Users/Name/anaconda/bin://anaconda/bin:/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/opt/X11/bin:/usr/texbin`

How do I remove the Anaconda path? I know that I have to change the .bash_profile, but **where exactly is the file located in Mac OS**?

Two additional side questions:

1) is the 'Python.framework' path part of the built in Mac python distribution, or is that related to Anaconda as well?

2) what is the /opt/X11/bin related to in the path?

Comment: Should be in the home folder  `/Users/Name/`. But may also be called `.profile`. If you don't see it in finder, you may have to enable seeing hidden files.

Comment: And to remove the path `export PATH=/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/opt/X11/bin:/usr/texbin` (I don't know where the `;` and the `&#‌​47` comes from, I don't see when editing the comment)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can edit bash profile with `vi ~/.bash_profile` make sure the PATH was not added in `~/.bashrc` or to `/etc/profile`

To remove the PATH you can either remove it from the file where it was added, or simply re export the ones you need `export PATH=/here/is/one:/here/is/another`

Comment: What if i cant open my Terminal. Where is the location in that context?

Answer (score 16):

1. Navigate to your user folder in Finder: `/Users/username/`
2. Make hidden files visible (the shortcut is <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>Cmd</kbd><kbd>.</kbd>)
3. Right click `.bash_profile` and **Open With...** your text editor of choice.
4. <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>Cmd</kbd><kbd>.</kbd> one more time in Finder to make hidden files invisible again. <sub>(Not required, just a good idea.)</sub>

Answer (score 1):

You can find the path in `/etc/paths` or `/Users/username/.bash_profile` or `/Users/username/.bash_login` or `/Users/username/.profile`.

Comment: Why would `.bash_profile` be located in `/etc/paths`?  Also, why ate you  referencing files not asked about?

Comment: On my mac (macOS Ventura 13.6), the paths were located in /etc/paths as Bearv5 suggested.